# wordpress get mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, templates

I'm using wordpress as a base for my website, I created a custom (not wp default) MySQL table with 3 columns in which I want to store simple informations such as Names, Birthdays and Email contacts. However I also want to create a page in my wordpress site that can connect to this specific database . i want to show this table data like wordpress posts template. Is there an easy way to do ?

```
<?php /* Template Name: CustomPageT1 */ ?>
<h1>This is my custom page</h1>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Points</th>
</tr>
<?php
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM sample_table" );
foreach ( $result as $print )   {
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $print->message;?></td>
</tr>
    <?php }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use wpdb class for that.

```
$new_connection = new wpdb('user','pass','database_name','localhost');
$result = $new_connection->get_results("select * from my_table");
foreach ( $result as $print )   {
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $print->message;?></td>
</tr>
<?php }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this pseudo code

In your template file you can use.

```
global $wpdb;    
$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM sample_table" );    
foreach ( $result as $print )   { 
echo $print->message;
}
```